# php SoapClient fails to connect, but command line curl call works

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, ssl-certificate

I have a LAMP server (#1) that is communicating via soap with another server (#2) via WSDL.  If I issue a curl call on the command line of server 1 to the URL of server 2, it works fine and get the appropriate WSDL response, but a php soapclient to the same URL is getting a "failed to load external entity" error.  This was working before when we had a self signed  certificate on server 2, but quit working about the same time we upgraded to a CA certificate.

Funny thing is this server is load balanced with another server at a different location (different OS, but same php code/database) and the second server isn't having any issues at all.

Here is the code I am using for the soap client:

```
function getSoapClient(){
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", 0);
    // standard soap client for application service
    $post_url = lum_getString("[CAMPAIGN_POST_URL]").
        "?enterprise=".lum_getString("[CAMPAIGN_ENTERPRISE]").
        "&company=".lum_getString("[CAMPAIGN_COMPANY]");
    $options = array(
        'trace' => true,
        'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
        'exceptions' => 1,
        'verifypeer' => false,
        'verifyhost' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true,
        'login' => lum_getString("[CAMPAIGN_POST_ID]"),
        'password' => lum_getString("[CAMPAIGN_POST_LC]"),
    );
    $context = stream_context_create(
        array(
            'user_agent' => 'PHPSoapClient',
            'ssl' => array(
                'verify_peer' => false,  
                'allow_self_signed' => true, 
            ),
            'https' => array(
                'curl_verify_ssl_peer'  => false,
                'curl_verify_ssl_host'  => false,
            )
        )
    );
    $options['stream_context'] = $context;

    $client = new SoapClient($post_url."&wsdl",$options);

    return $client;
}
```

The curl and soapclient are using the same ports so it shouldn't be a firewall issue.

Any help in identifying the issue or helping me figure what is wrong is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I made sure that the openssl versions matched between the working load balanced machine and the broken client server #1, downgrading the broken server #1 to version 1.01, with no affect.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it appears to be a firewall issue.  I opened up all access from server 1 to server 2 and things started working.  Not too sure what the issue was.   I reduced the options to just the login and password, it's still working.  Firewalls are often the answer.

Any ideas regarding the firewall, the correct ports, and why it wasn't working is much appreciated.

Why was cURL working and SOAP not?